# Getting multiple types using Google Places API now deprecated

Tags: javascript, android, google-places-api

Google has recently announced that:

"The types parameter is deprecated as of February 16, 2016, replaced by a new type parameter which only supports one type per search request."

My question is this: Is there now any way (not using deprecated parameters) to get multiple place types from a single API call?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not :/

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Does anybody know something new?