# Alternative to searching multiple types using Google Nearby Search

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

Due to google deprecate their "Types" parameter in Feb 2017, I can only search for nearby places using a single filter now.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);

        int radius= numberpicker.getValue();
        radius=radius *1000;
        //Todo: figure out how to support multiple type..........
        sb.append("&radius="+Integer.toString(radius));
        sb.append("&types=" +LocationType1+"|" +LocationType2); //etc etc 
        sb.append("&sensor=true");
        sb.append("&key=AIzaSyDkIa12Y9nXORou_xCnwS09K53kbJabKHo");
```

Originally I planned to do something like this, but since the "Types" is deprecated what should I do to be able to search for different types aside from searching using different type multiple types?

I have seen the same question here but there is still no answer there.

[Getting multiple types using Google Places API now deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632944/getting-multiple-types-using-google-places-api-now-deprecated)